# How to return the original data frame with only the rows selected using value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas

the original dataframe:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
%pylab inline

df=pd.read_csv('NYC_Restaurants.csv', dtype=unicode)
```

[image: original df]

I used a mask to isolate the desired rows (those that occur only once in the column)

```
mask = df['DBA'].value_counts()[df['DBA'].value_counts() == 1]
```

which produces the expected result

However, using `df[mask]` produces a strange dataframe with the first column repeated many times; as opposed to giving back the original dataframe with only the selected rows

[image: Output from using mask]

Comment: Can you add the code to initialize your dataframe?

Comment: Please dont use png for data or tables.

Comment: from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
%pylab inline

df=pd.read_csv('NYC_Restaurants.csv', dtype=unicode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using value_counts(); I used groupby which provided exactly what I was looking for.

```
mask = df.groupby("DBA").filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
```